# No token is generating, with valid username and password using APIclient()

Tags: python-2.7, django-rest-framework, http-post, auth-token, apiclient

I am trying to generate token from from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token. View is successfully created, but I am writing test for post api using APIClient() from rest_framework.test import APIClient.
def test_address_api_auth_token(self):

```
    data = {
        "username": self.user.username,
        "password": self.user.password
    }
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
    response = self.client.post('/api-token-auth/', data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Although user and password are created by model. but still I am getting this error -> AssertionError: 400 != 200. 
Error message -> Invalid usernamen and password .

Answer (score 0):

Django stores password encrypted. Therefore, by doing `self.user.password` you're sending another string and will always fail the authentication.